# apt-get update stuck; possibly redirects to prod.debian.map.fastly.net

Tags: debian, apt

Things were probably fine before I installed postfix, dovecot and roundcube. And then `apt-get update` stopped working. It's stuck with this line:

```
 0% [Connecting to prod.debian.map.fastly.net (2a04:4e42:3::204)] [Connecting to prod.debian.map.fastly.net (2a04:4e42:3::204)]
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you have any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: No. There seems to be error with networks.

Comment: I had a similar problem, simply reboot solved the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`deb.debian.org`](http://deb.debian.org/) provides a CDN-based Debian repository; as you can see in the linked page, `prod.debian.map.fastly.net` is one of the hosts used to implement the service.

It looks like you’re having connectivity issues to that server, either specifically related to the server, or more general IPv6 issues.

You can choose [another mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) and replace the `deb.debian.org` entries in your `sources.list` file as appropriate.